# Flattening Maybes

Tags: haskell, option-type

I often have a code that has "maybe Nothing someFunc" pattern:

```
instance FromJSON SaveSection where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
      SaveSection <$>
      o .:? "eventId" <*>
      (maybe Nothing parseUSDate <$> o .:? "eventDate") <*>
      o .:? "eventRecId" <*>
      o .:? "idxId" <*>
      (maybe Nothing parseUSDate <$> o .:? "idxDate") <*>
      o .:? "idxRecId"
```

Here `parseUSDate` has type `Text -> Maybe Date`.

Aeson parsing obviously returns `Maybe Text`.

So it looks to me that I need to lift through 2 layers of `Maybe` here. And I have no clue how to do it any other way but with `maybe Nothing someFunc` pattern.

Am I missing some obvious "flatten" or whatever function that I could use here?

**EDIT:** Thanks for Alexey's answer.

This is exactly what i was looking for. Here's the end result:

```
instance FromJSON SaveSection where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
      SaveSection <$>
      o .:? "eventId" <*>
      ((>>= parseUSDate) <$> o .:? "eventDate") <*>
      o .:? "eventRecId" <*>
      o .:? "idxId" <*>
      ((>>= parseUSDate) <$> o .:? "idxDate") <*>
      o .:? "idxRecId"
```

Comment: Might be time to read [All About Monads](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads) :o

Comment: Check the edits to my answer, I think that should help out better.  My initial attempt wasn't quite right, but I believe it to be fixed now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `f' = maybe Nothing f`, then the types have to be `f :: a -> Maybe b` and `f' :: Maybe a -> Maybe b` (where `a` and `b` may be variables or specific types), or it won't type-check. But this is just the type of [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) for the `Maybe` monad: `Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b`! So `maybe Nothing f` can be written as `(>>= f)`.

Comment: Cool, hadn't realized that `(>>=) = maybe Nothing`.

Comment: @luqui Well, to be more precise `(>>=) = flip (maybe Nothing)`.

Comment: Thx. Amazing insight for noobs like me!

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, oh right, braino. `(=<<) = maybe Nothing`.  (I prefer `(=<<)`, so it feels more fundamental)

Answer (score 10):

There's the ever-handy `Control.Monad.join` function:

```
> join (Just (Just 1))
Just 1
> join (Just Nothing)
Nothing
> join Nothing
Nothing
```

I'm not an expert on Aeson, but if I do:

```
> :m Control.Monad Control.Applicative Data.Aeson Data.Text
> :set -XOverloadedStrings
> :set +m 
> let f :: Text -> Maybe Text
|     f = Just    -- Stand-in for parseUSDate
> :t \o -> join <$> liftM f <$> o .:? "key"
Object -> Parser (Maybe Text)
> -- Has the same type as your expression
> :t \o -> maybe Nothing f <$> o .:? "key"
Object -> Parser (Maybe Text)
```

Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

EDIT: Fixed so that it actually works... My initial generic `f :: a -> Maybe a` was messing things up.

---

You could make an operator to clean this up:

```
infixl 9
(>>=$) :: (Functor f, Monad m) => f (m a) -> (a -> m b) -> f (m b)
m >>=$ a = join <$> liftM a <$> m

parseJSON (Object o) =
    SaveSection
        <$> o .:? "eventId"
        <*> o .:? "eventDate" >>=$ parseUSDate
        <*> o .:? "eventRecId"
        <*> o .:? "idxId"
        <*> o .:? "idxDate" >>=$ parseUSDate
        <*> o .:? "idxRecId"
```

(This should work...)

Comment: Thx, indeed worked. But this solution is even more convoluted and hard to read than straight maybe Nothing pattern. Compare:
(maybe Nothing parseUSDate <$> o .:? "eventDate") <*> ---------- 

(join <$> (parseUSDate <$>) <$> join <$> o .:? "eventDate") <*>

Comment: @VagifVerdi I think my latest update should help you out there, I factored out the ugly pattern into an operator (feel free to change it to something that might be more intuitive, I just tried to combine `>>=` and `<$>`) and I'd say that the result makes it much more clean.

Comment: Although you might have to fiddle with the fixity of the operator to get it to play nice with `<*>`, I don't have all your code so it's hard to test.

Comment: Thx, your answer was helpful to understand how join works. I accepted Alexey's answer because (>== f) is just amazing, incredibly concise yet clear and easy to read. Plus it is a mind boggling insight for a noob like me.